# obtain other values corresponding to a given value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that has alot of data in it.

Sample of JSON file:

```
{
   "thefirst": {
    "one": {
        "color1": "red",
        "color2": "blue"
    },
    "two": {
        "color3": "green",
        "color4": "purple"
    },
    "three": {
        "color5": "yellow",
        "color6": "white"
    }
   },
   "thesecond": {
    "one": {
        "color1": "black",
        "color2": "grey"
    },
    "two": {
        "color3": "navy",
        "color4": "white"
    },
    "three": {
        "color5": "purple",
        "color6": "red"
    }
   },
   "thethird": {
    "one": {
        "color1": "maroon",
        "color2": "white"
    },
    "two": {
        "color3": "red",
        "color4": "orange"
    },
    "three": {
        "color5": "green",
        "color6": "blue"
    }
   }
}
```

My question is, with the use of either Jquery(client side) `$.getJSON...`, or `php`, is it possible to get the corresponding value of a given value?
So, for example for every `red` value I would like the corresponding value to `red`. So for the sample above, that would be `blue`, `purple` and `orange`.

I don't know if its possible, so I'm unsure how to go about it.

I was wondering if utilising the Jquery `$.each(array, function (key, value))...` would work, or using php possibly generate a `loop` and/or `foreach ($key => $Value)` once the JSON file was decoded, `json_decode`.

But i'm not really sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes you need to loop throgh it and make a logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode your **`JSON`** data and nest two levels and apply the logic as shown. See the working demo below.

```
<?php

$arr =json_decode($json,1); //<------- Pass your JSON string into the $json variable.
$str = "";
$keyword='red'; //<------- Pass any color you want to get its corresponding match
foreach($arr as $arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $arr3)
    {
       foreach($arr3 as $k=>$v)
        {
            if(in_array($keyword,$arr3))
            {
            $str.=implode(' ',$arr3)." ";
            }
        }
    }
}
$str=trim(str_replace($keyword,'',$str));
$str_arr = explode(' ',$str);

print_r(array_values(array_filter(array_unique($str_arr),'strlen')));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => purple
    [2] => orange
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100755)

---

> Thank you for the help. That is what I was looking for. One question,
>   if I wanted to save that output array into new json file could i use
>   json_encode and the file_put_contents method?

### The code...

```
$outputarr =  array_values(array_filter(array_unique($str_arr),'strlen'));
$jsonencstring = json_encode($outputarr); //<-- This is a JSON now
file_put_contents('yourfilename.txt',$jsonencstring);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is what I was looking for. One question, if I wanted to save that output array into new json file could i use `json_encode` and the `file_put_contents` method?

Comment: @user1648449, Edited the answer as per your needs.